# Finding the oldest customers in a sql database

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to find the oldest person in a SQL database that has the following configuration:

```
Customers (
    cardNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first TEXT,
    last TEXT,
    sex CHAR,
    dob DATE
)
```

I'm trying to find the oldest customers in the database, of which there are 28 (they have the same dob). I'm not sure how to get multiple results from the min() keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery.

Something like:

```
SELECT first, last FROM Customers
WHERE
    dob = (SELECT MIN(dob) FROM Customers);
```

Comment: Very simple answer. Not sure how I didn't think of that myself considering the number of variations I tried. Any idea how I can get it to list out the customers with last name appearing first?

Comment: @Mdomin45 Just change the order of the fields as they appear between the "SELECT" and the "FROM".

Answer (score 0):

I believe that **MIN() / MAX()** is an aggregate function which means that it returns a single scalar value.

More info for the aggregate functions can be found here: [Aggregate functions info](http://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-aggregate-functions/)

But to solve your problem, The query should be like this.

**MS SQL**

```
SELECT
 c.first,
 c.last
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.dob IS NOT NULL
AND c.dob = (
    SELECT TOP 1 cc.dob 
    FROM Customers cc 
    WHERE cc.dob IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY cc.dob
)
GROUP BY c.dob
ORDER BY c.dob
```

**SQL LITE**

```
SELECT
 c.first,
 c.last
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.dob IS NOT NULL
AND c.dob = (
    SELECT cc.dob 
    FROM Customers cc 
    WHERE cc.dob IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY cc.dob
    LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY c.dob
ORDER BY c.dob
```

I think it will still need optimization. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Sqlite doesn't support TOP N syntax, btw.

Comment: Hello @Shawn, Almost caused a disaster for the OP. I didn't know that Sql lite and MS Sql has different approach for selecting top 1. Learned something new today. Thanks! :)